# Strapi with mySQL database

Tags: mysql, strapi, npx

I'm trying to set up Strapi on my server, and we already use mySQL databases. But I'm having a hard time finding setup instructions for anything other than Mongo or sqLite. Anyone have any steps or tips?

Whenever I try running `npx create-strapi-app [name]` and go through the options like so:

```
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Choose your default database client mysql
? Database name: [db_name]
? Host: 127.0.0.1
? Port: 3306
? Username: [user_name]
? Password: [password]
? Enable SSL connection: No
```

I get the following error:

```
 :no_entry:️ Connection test failed: Command failed: /bin/sh -c npm install --prefix /tmp/strapid0c093a76d5c strapi-connector-bookshelf@3.0.0-beta.18 knex@<0.20.0 mysql@latest
/bin/sh: 0.20.0: No such file or directory
```

I'm doing this on a Linux based server

Comment: Can you please try with the last version of strapi.
We had some issues when we publish the beta.18.
Butt it's fixed now.

Comment: Hi Jim Laurie, actually managed to get it working by creating it for SQLite and then modifying the database.json file accordingly

Comment: As @Phil said you can modify the db creds after using `npx create-strapi-app test-app --quickstart` or provide db credentials manually as you are doing. Remember the db creds you are going to provide should exist.